# Error occured when trying to enable spfeature via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

When try to execute `enable-spfeature –identify "OffWfCommon" –url http://site`. How to fix this?

> Enable-SPFeature : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'identify'. At line:1 char:18
>   + enable-spfeature -identify "OffWfCommon"    -url  http://site
>   +                  ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-SPFeature], Paramet    erBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.Powe
>   rShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature

Answer (score 2):

It should read `-Identity`

```
Enable-SPFeature –Identity "OffWfCommon" –url http://site
```